# Pagination rule for Post API call in data factory

Tags: azure, api, rest, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have a url that returns a response json based on following details:

```
https://testapi/dev?user=reportuser

Call type: POST

Body: {
    "name": "Employee Data",
    "pageSize": "10000",
    "nextTableName": "EMPLOYEE",
    "nextKey": "1",
    "tables": [
        {
            "tableName": "EMPLOYEE",
            "columns": [
                "FIRST_NAME",
                "LAST_NAME",
                "ADDRESS",
        ]
    }
]
```

}

```
Response JSON:
    {
     "data": {
        "EMPLOYEE": [
            {
                "FIRST_NAME":"Rahul",
                "LAST_NAME":"Sharma",
                "ADDRESS":"UK"
            },
            {
                "FIRST_NAME":"Albert",
                "LAST_NAME":"Wintermeyer",
                "ADDRESS":"Australia"
            },
            ...
            ...
         ],
         "pagination": [
            {
                "nextTableName": "EMPLOYEE",
                "nextKey": "10001"
            }
        ]
}
```

}

To explain how the url works, it returns first 10000 records starting from the 1st when (because of nextKey:1).

If I want to query the next 10000 records, I replace nextKey in body with 10001 and it will return all records from 10001 to 20001.

One keeps calling these till nextKey in response returns 0.

I want to move this data to Azure SQL database and I am using azure data factory for this. I tried with Web activity, but there is a payload limit of 4MB. Because of this endless number of calls need to be made to reach the end.

All the articles I have gone through suggest the direct way of using paginaton rule, i.e. in response json I will get link to the next set of data called nextLink. In my case I just get a number (nextKey).

How do I use pagination rule of copy data activity in a way that I can send the whole body with new nextKey value and url again.

Note: Its a POST call, hence body has to be sent everytime (with new nextkey value).

Answer (score 0):

> I use pagination rule of copy data activity in a way that I can send the whole body with new nextKey value and url again.

AFAIK, you can't directly fetch API response to API body. you check this similar [issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1188835/how-to-configure-adf-copy-data-rest-api-pagination) also.

You can follow below approach to achieve your scenario:

- First create a set variable to store **next key** with value 1.
  [image]
- Then take a until activity to check the end condition as **if `nextkey` is equal to 0 the stop the iteration**.
  [image]
- Then inside until loop take a copy activity to copy data from rest Api to SQL and pass body as

```json
{
    "name": "Employee Data",
    "pageSize": "10000",
    "nextTableName": "EMPLOYEE",
    "nextKey": "@{variables('nextkey')}",
    "tables": [
        {
            "tableName": "EMPLOYEE",
            "columns": [
                "FIRST_NAME",
                "LAST_NAME",
                "ADDRESS"
                ]
        }
    ]
}
```

so it will take value of next key from set variable and then call the response and copy it in sql table.
[image]

- Then again call the same API with the web activity to get the `nextkey` value from API response with same request body as above.
  [image]
- After this take another set variable to update the `nextkey` value which we set earlier with web activity responses `nextkey` .
  [image]
- So, it will update the `nextkey` value and iterate based on that value again in until loop till it match with condition.